# Require __AdditionalEmailAttributes

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can anyone help me think of a way to require values for the __AdditionalEmailAttribute1 and __AdditionalEmailAttribute2 fields when building an email? I am currently creating emails using HTML pastes.

The way I am doing it today is with a content block that I have to include on each email...

```
<!--%%[

IF empty(__AdditionalEmailAttribute1) OR empty(__AdditionalEmailAttribute2) THEN
]%%-->

<table style="background:red;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:20px;">
      __AdditionalEmailAttributes missing!!!
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--%%[ endif ]%%-->
```

But I feel like maybe there is a way to require those values much like Email Name and Subject are required.

Comment: Hi Daniel, what values do you want to store in the AdditionalEmailAddributes? Are those values likely to change for each email/campaign/send? Is the data stored anywhere in SFMC, or could it be queried from another source (Google Analytics, etc)?

Comment: I will be storing utm_campaign and utm_term values, which will be unique for each and every send. (ie: utm_campaign=[YYYYMMDD_email_name], utm_term=[email_type, internally used value, only about 40 different types]) And I have dynamic content blocks being pulled into each email. These values aren't going to be stored in a DE or anything, I'd like to plug them in quickly like I do the email name, subject, etc. Thanks, so far!